# Run script error : No such file or directory

Tags: ios, xcode, bash

I am getting this error when I tried to run a test in my project. I have added one framework as a embeded framework in my project. The exact error message is

```
bash: /Users/<username>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<ProjectName>-cnpqefdtutjgjdaulkqwjbbvbfnu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/<ProjectName>Tests.xctest/Frameworks/LayerKit.framework/strip-frameworks.sh: No such file or directory
```

I have followed all the steps to add an embeded framework to Xcode. But still no use.

BTW, I am using pods.

Comment: This may help you. Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33377027/xcode-unable-to-find-strip-frameworks-sh-directory

Comment: Unfortunately @RohitWankhede , I have done exactly the link is suggesting. But still no use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this answer, in case it will help somebody else.

While installing pod which will also connect to our test targets. We need to write podfile as follows ,

```
def shared_pods 
specify pods here
end  


target 'AppName' do  
shared_pods 
end 


target 'AppNameTests' do 
shared_pods 
end
```

Adding the target entry in your Podfile will cause CocoaPods to generate a new set of files the next time you run `pod install`. However, before you run that command, you will probably need to set your configurations to None, so that Cocoapods can assign its own configuration. Here's how to do that:

1. Go to your project-level target
2. For each configuration listed under Configurations, select None for your target, in the drop-down menu under Based on Configuration File.

Once you've edited your Podfile and you nullified your configurations, you're ready to run `pod install` on the command line. After the process is completed, check back with your base configuration settings, and note that they have been set to the configuration file that was generated by CocoaPods!

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem before.

First try to Clean the project, by pressing - `Cmd+Shift+K` and the cache folder - `Cmd+Alt+Shift+K`.
Make sure that you have the latest version of the LayerKit in your Podfile:

```
target 'YourAppName' do
  pod 'LayerKit', '~> 0.22'
end
```

And then run `pod update`

I hope I've helped!

Comment: Sorry @deyanm but above thing didnt work, please check my answer which worked for me.

Comment: Ok, thank you @TusharJ. I didn't saw your reply before mine!